# ArrayList elements with state

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Let's say I have an `ArrayList` of objects - for example, sprites on a screen.

I loop through these objects to calculate what they do next, but in order to do that I'd have had to kept their previous state (e.g., in order to know that object `A` should be moved to the right, I'd have to know that previously we were already moving it to the right).

Objects might be added or removed to the `ArrayList` at any time.

Given that this object didn't come with a way to keep track of this, what's the best way to keep state?

Comment: Create a class for the sprites with a previous state property, then you can create objects of this class and you have access to the previous state.

Comment: @derp, please mark the answer that helped you solve your issue as 'accepted'.

Comment: Whoops, done. sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option, if you can do so, would be to extend the sprite class into a subclass that does keep track of the previous position. Whether you can do this depends on where your `ArrayList` is coming from, though: you might or might not have control over the construction of the instances.

If you can't, I would suggest using a `HashMap` from these objects to something that stores the state you need to track (for instance, previous position).

When you update, you can then loop through the `ArrayList`, and look each object up in the map to find where it used to be. You'll then want to update its position on the screen, and update the map's cache of the previous position to the new position.

Another option would be to create a wrapper object that includes a sprite by composition, and also contains its previous position, and then store these wrapper objects in your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the object and implement a state-tracking mechanism, then make the ArrayList take objects of this new type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList, so as to keep track of the state of the previous object.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on your logic, in the real sense there is no best way to keep previous state. but i you a `static` variable in the Object class to keep track of the state of the last thing done. because a `static` variable or function belongs to the class not an instance of an object, hence it can be used to keep track of all the stuff affecting the class

Comment: Using globally-scoped variables is bad practice if the state pertains to a specific collection.